# С++ ругается на массив

Tags: c++, массивы

ошибка: expression must have a constant value the value of variable (declared at line 19) cannot be used as a constant

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не совсем понимаю, что у меня не так, переменная "sh" объявлена как константа.

Comment: Компилятор ждет от вас константу времени компиляции, а-ля `const int sh = 42;`. Если размер известен только в рантайме, используйте `std::vector` вместо массива.

Comment: В современных компиляторах используйте для таких случаев, как размер массива, `constexpr`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat с vector-ом особо не хочу возиться, особенно с двумерным,он как-то странно заполняется.

Comment: `vector<vector<unsigned int>> rez(sh, vector<unsigned int>(3));`. Заполнятся будет также как и обычный двумерный массив через два индекса: `rez[i][j]`

Comment: @GermanShtykmauser У вас выбора особо нет. Либо вектор, либо дергать `new` руками. Второе в приличном обществе не делают, разве что для тренировки.

Comment: Если не пугает, что обращаться к i,j-му элементу придется не `res[i][j]`, а `res[i * 3 + j]`, то выделяйте память -- `int *res = malloc(sizeof(int) * sh * 3);` и вперед (просто и надежно, проверено поколениями)

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать

```
constexpr int sh = n;
```

и массиву станет хорошо... А вот этому присваиванию - вряд ли.

Comment: the value of variable n cannot be used as constant (n - обычный int)

Comment: @GermanShtykmauser, я так и думал.

Comment: Придется все-таки вектор использовать